# Parsing py2neo paths into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, neo4j, py2neo

We are returning `paths`  from a `cypher` query using `py2neo`. We would like to parse the result into a `Pandas DataFrame`. The `cypher` query is similar to the following query

```
query='''MATCH p=allShortestPaths(p1:Type1)-[r*..3]-(p2:Type1)
WHERE p1.ID =123456
RETURN distinct(p)''
result = graph.run(query)
```

The resulting object is a [walkable](http://py2neo.org/v3/types.html#Walkable) object - which can be traversed. It should be noted that the `Nodes` and `Relationships` don't have the same properties.
What would be the most `pythonic` way to iterate over the object? Is it necessary to process the entire path or since the object is a dictionary is it possible to use the `Pandas.from_dict` method? There is an issue that sometimes the length of the paths are not equal.
Currently we are enumerating the object and if it is an un-equal object then it is a [Node](http://py2neo.org/v3/types.html#Node) , otherwise we process the object as a [relationship](http://py2neo.org/v3/types.html#Relationship).

```
for index, item in enumerate(paths):
  if index%2 == 0:
    #process as Node
  else:
    #process as Relationship
```

We can use the `isinstance` method i.e.

```
 if isinstance(item, py2neo.types.Node ):
   #process as Node
```

But that still requires processing every element separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem as follows:
I wrote a function that receives a list of paths with the properties of the nodes and relationships

```
def neo4j_graph_to_dict(paths, node_properties, rels_properties):   
    paths_dict=OrderedDict()
    for (pathID, path) in enumerate(paths):
        paths_dict[pathID]={}
        for (i, node_rel) in enumerate(path):
            n_properties = [node_rel[np] for np in node_properties]
            r_properties = [node_rel[rp] for rp in rels_properties]
            if isinstance(node_rel, Node):
                node_fromat = [np+': {}|'for np in node_properties]
                paths_dict[pathID]['Node'+str(i)]=('{}: '+' '.join(node_fromat)).format(list(node_rel.labels())[0], *n_properties)                
            elif isinstance(node_rel, Relationship):
                rel_fromat = [np+': {}|'for np in rels_properties]
                reltype= 'Rel'+str(i-1)
                paths_dict[pathID][reltype]= ('{}: '+' '.join(rel_fromat)).format(node_rel.type(), *r_properties)
    return paths_dict
```

Assuming the query returns the paths, nodes and relationships we can run the following code:

```
query='''MATCH paths=allShortestPaths(
    (pr1:Type1 {ID:'123456'})-[r*1..9]-(pr2:Type2 {ID:'654321'}))  
    RETURN paths, nodes(paths) as nodes, rels(paths) as rels'''  

df_qf = pd.DataFrame(graph.data(query))
node_properties = set([k for series in df_qf.nodes for node in series for k in node.keys() ]) # get unique values for Node properites
rels_properties = set([k for series in df_qf.rels for rel in series for k in rel.keys() ]) # get unique values for Rels properites
wg = [(walk(path))  for path in df_qf.paths ]
paths_dict = neo4j_graph_to_dict(wg, node_properties, rels_properties)
df = pd.DataFrame(paths_dict).transpose()
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=paths_dict[0].keys()).drop_duplicates()
```